# Закрытие notification

Tags: android, уведомления

```
private void addNotification1(String ss) {
    String ssBigText = ss;
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .setTicker("")
            .setContentTitle("")
            .setContentText(ss)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.a)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), R.drawable.logoapp))
            .setOngoing(true)
            .addAction(0, "",
                    intent).setAutoCancel(true);
    Notification notification = builder.getNotification();
    long[] vibrate = new long[] { 0, 0, 200, 30, 10 };
    notification.vibrate = vibrate;
    notification.priority =Notification.PRIORITY_MAX;
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notification.flags = notification.flags | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
    nm.notify(NOTIFY_ID, notification);
}
```

поставил флаг ongoing и флаг auto cancel но при нажатии се равно не закрывается ,что я не правильно делаю?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 private void addNotification1(String ss) {
        String ssBigText = ss;
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .setTicker("")
                .setContentTitle("")
                .setContentText(ss)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round))
                .setOngoing(true)
//                .addAction(0, "", intent) // вот это заменил
                .setContentIntent(intent)  // на это
                .setAutoCancel(true);
        Notification notification = builder.getNotification();
        long[] vibrate = new long[] { 0, 0, 200, 30, 10 };
        notification.vibrate = vibrate;
        notification.priority =Notification.PRIORITY_MAX;
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notification.flags = notification.flags | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

        //спустил NotificationManager отдельно вниз
        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        nm.notify(1, notification);
    }
```

Проверил ваш код со своими изменениями, работает теперь.

Посмотрите 3 моих комментария:

```
//                .addAction(0, "", intent) // вот это заменил
            .setContentIntent(intent)  // на это

//спустил NotificationManager отдельно вниз
    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nm.notify(1, notification);
```

Скорее всего у Вас `.addAction(0, "", intent)` не настроен. Но если не принципиально, используйте написанный мной